# Can I use a set type as an array index?

Tags: arrays, delphi, set, type-safety

I cannot use a `set` type as an size indicator for an array, however doing so for small sets is perfectly sensible.

Suppose I have the following code:

```
  TFutureCoreSet = set of 0..15;
  TLookupTable = record
    FData: array[TFutureCoreSet] of TSomeRecord; //error ordinal type required
  ....
```

The following code compiles and works.

```
  TFutureCoreSet = set of 0..15;
  TLookupTable = record
    FData: array[word] of TSomeRecord;
```

This however breaks the link between the allowed number of states in `TFutureCoreSet` and the elements in the lookup table.
Is there a simple way to link the two so when one changes the other updates as well?

Comment: How would you index such array? `FData[[1, 2, 4]] := SomeRecord`? Think about all the combinations when accessing such array..

Comment: @Victoria, The set has 16 bits, so the array will have 64k elements. You just use the ordinal value of the set as the lookup value. Nothing complicated. Up to 20 bits its perfectly doable to use a lookuptable. With `set of byte` that obviously will not work :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just do it slightly differently:

```
type
  TFutureCore = 0..15;
  TFutureCoreSet = set of TFutureCore;
  TFutureCoreIndex = 0..(2 shl High(TFutureCore)) - 1;
  TLookupTable = record
    FData: array[TFutureCoreIndex] of TSomeRecord;
  end;
```

The other advantage of using a `TFutureCoreIndex` is that you can use it to typecast `TFutureCoreSet` to an ordinal type. When typecasting a set type you must cast to an ordinal type of the same size.

```
AllowedStates = LookupTable.FData[TFutureCoreIndex(FutureCores)]; //works
AllowedStates = LookupTable.FData[Integer(FutureCores)]; //invalid typecast
AllowedStates = LookupTable.FData[Word(FutureCores)]; //works, but not type safe.
```

Comment: I think `1 shl ... - 1` is correct. 1 shl 16 = 65536, minus one: 65535.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, but `High(TFutureCore)` is 15 and `2 shl 15` is the same as  `1 shl (15+1)`.

Comment: Yes, this will also fix the fact that you can only cast a set to an integer type with the exact same size. BTW would `0..1 shl High(TFutureCore)` not be cleaner, or did I miss something.

Comment: @Johan: 1 shl 15 = 32768

Comment: `shl` is stronger than minus!

Comment: Thanks Uwe, that was most helpful.